# Creating a d3 selection over an existing, detached SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a component in JavaScript that will provide an `<svg>` element to its host. I want to populate the SVG element using d3.js.

If I let d3.js create the SVG element and add it to the `<body>`, then things work as expected:

```
var chart = d3.select('body').append('svg');
```

However I already have an SVG element. I want my code to more closely resemble:

```
var svg = document.createElement('svg'),
    chart = d3.select(svg);
```

This latter approach populates the SVG element (as seen in the elements panel of Chrome's developer tools) but it does not render properly.

Am I going about this incorrectly?

I don't mind if d3 creates the SVG element, so long as it doesn't attach it to the DOM and I can access it.

---

**EDIT** I've created a [jsFiddle that reproduces my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/JVrPw/). You can toggle the `APPROACH` variable between 1 and 2 to see alternate approaches. I see this issue in both Chrome and Firefox (latest versions on Ubuntu 13.04.)

---

**EDIT 2** I've created a screenshot showing the working and non-working versions side by side:

[image]

You can see that the element trees are largely the same. However on the non-working version (left) the *Styles* panel (to the right of the element tree) is missing some user agent rules. I have no idea why this should be different. I'd suggest it was a bug in Chrome, but the same behaviour is visible in Firefox.

Comment: This approach should work -- what do you mean when you say that it doesn't render properly?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/JVrPw/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the SVG element in the HTML namespace where it gets interpreted incorrectly. If you replace

```
var svg = document.createElement('svg');
```

with

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg');
```

it works fine. D3 takes care of this for you by setting the namespace automatically.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't know that the `<svg>` element resided in another namespace. I've never seen it prefixed before (`xmlns:svg=...` and `<svg:svg>`), so why isn't that necessary? Will do some Googling. Thanks again.

Comment: Ugh, too slow :). You can also use `d3.ns.prefix.svg` to supply the namespace URI - see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/KzwjM/